# Remove all consecutive blank lines, leaving just one: perl -00 -pe ''

Tags: perl

I try to understand the following Perl command to "remove all consecutive blank lines, leaving just one":

```
perl -00 -pe ''
```

From [Perl One-Liners Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-one/):

> First of all it does not have any code, the -e is empty. Next it has a
>   silly -00 command line option. This command line option turns
>   paragraph slurp mode on. A paragraph is text between two newlines. All
>   the other newlines get ignored. The paragraph gets put in "$_" and the
>   "-p" option prints it out.

I do not follow this explanation. Maybe the wording is not accurate.

So `"A paragraph is text between two newlines."` But every line is text between two newlines.

`"All the other newlines get ignored."` But there are no newlines between two successive newlines.

`"The paragraph gets put in "$_" and the "-p" option prints it out."` Since it does it to the text between every two newlines, that would cram together the whole file into one long line. How does it look like what they say this command is supposed to do?

It also says that an alternative way to write it is

```
perl -00pe0
```

What does the rightmost `0` represent?

Anyway, What I actually want to achieve is to **remove all consecutive white lines**, leaving just **one empty line**. By white line I mean a line that may be not empty, but only has whitespace characters (and newline).
Is it possible to modify the above command to match this case?

Comment: Any source that says *"Next it has a silly -00 command line option"* is not to be trusted.

Comment: The second `0` is the argument to `-e`, i.e. the program to run.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to read the official documentation when in doubt. See `-0` in [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) and `$/` in [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar).

The text should have said

> A paragraph is text **delimited** by two **or more** newlines.

"All other newlines" then become the newlines that don't come in pairs. "Ignored" means they don't separate paragraphs, but they are included in the strings read from the input.

`-e0` just executes `0` as the code. 0 and 1 are exempt from [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings), any other value would work too, but with `-w` would warn you:

```
Useless use of a constant (2) in void context at -e line 1.
```

To achieve what you want, you can process the file in two steps: First, remove any whitespace from whitespace only lines

```
perl -lpe 's/^\s+$//'
```

(The `-l` is needed not to remove the newlines together with all the whitespace ).

Then run the already known

```
perl -00pe0
```

So, the whole pipeline becomes

```
perl -lpe 's/^\s+$//' -- file | perl -00pe0
```

You can, of course, do all the work in one call to `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\S/)         { $in_sep = ! print }
          elsif (! $in_sep) { $in_sep = print "\n" }' -- file
```

$in_sep remembers whether we are "in a separator", only the first time we enter such a whitespace block a newline is printed.

Comment: This is excellent except that you don't explain properly what `-l` does and how it affects `perl -lpe 's/^\s+$//'`

Comment: `$in_sep = ! print` is horrible

Comment: What does the `--` mean? I want to have this script change the original file, not just push the output to the console, so I try `perl -lpe 's/^\s+$//' -- file | perl -i -00pe0` however the output still goes to the console, why is that? Maybe it's because in the last part of the pipe the input file is stdout, so how can I push the changes to the original file?

Comment: Either try the one call version, or redirect output to a temp file and rename it to the original afterwards. That's what `-i` does, anyway.

Comment: @Borodin what is horrible about it?

Comment: @rapt: Can you explain what it does?

Answer (score 1):

The [`B::Deparse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) module
may be used to reveal the effective code behind a one-line program.
It can be enabled in a one-liner by adding `-MO=Deparse` like this

```
perl -MO=Deparse -00 -p -e 0
```

The `-0` option sets the value of `$/`: the *input record separator*, and setting it to empty string `""` with `-00` enables "paragraph mode" which means the input will be split at one or more blank lines

Another special values for `-0` are `-0777`, which disables the record separator so that the whole file is read. And `$/` may be set to `\<number>`, like `\8192`, so as to input records with a fixed length, but this is unavailable through the `-0` option

If the file is not too long, read the whole file

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\s+\n/\n\n/g'
```

Otherwise the file can be read in chunks of, say, 8192 bytes, but in certain cases the next chunk must be read before processing.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $/ = \8192} $_ .= <> while /\n\s*$/ && ! eof; s/\n\s+\n/\n\n/g'
```

Comment: Please don't compress your code when writing an answer. While you may want to inflict illegible code on yourself, it is inappropriate to do make an answer on *Stack Overflow* so opaque.

Comment: @Borodin, thank you for your feedback, the reason of short code was one-liner, i agree with some space it's easier to understand.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul The first one you suggested was actually easier to understand, once I figured out the regex :) Is the second one going to work if the chunk cuts a white paragraph in the middle? Could I not get at least 2 newlines for it?

Comment: just for info `\s` matches also `\n` and because of greediness by default matches the longest match, the case of a chunk which ends in the middle of a white paragraph is handled by while loop, i just added this answer to show it existed another way to do it but the other answer may be easier in case of large files (more than 100M). Note that any delimiter other than newline or blank can be used for example `perl -0056pe's/\n\s+\n/\n\n/g'` should work also